# Multi arch ELF binary: Is it possible with custom sections?

Tags: elf

If one is able to create custom sections in an ELF file then is it feasible/possible to dump machine code of different CPU arch into the same ELF file in different section and at runtime map the correct `.text` section based on the current machine ? Would this not allow for universal binary distribution based on the ELF format ? I get the downside of this is that the executable size would be huge, but from a concept point/experimentation point of view is the idea possible ?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/359070/) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary)?

Comment: yep that prety much about covers it. Thanks.